# How to load events in FullCalendar from XML?

Tags: xml, fullcalendar, init

I'm in this situation, I would like to load events from an XML file and I'm using this code:

```
events: function(start, end, callback) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/contracts/'+contract_id+'.xml',
      dataType: 'xml',              
      data: {
        // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
        start: Math.round(start.getTime() / 1000),
        end: Math.round(end.getTime() / 1000)
      },

      success: function(doc) {
        var events = [];
        $(doc).find('contract').each(function() {
          events.push({
            title: $(this).attr('week-mon-hours'),
            start: $(this).attr('week-mon-hours') // will be parsed
          });
        });
        callback(events);
      }
    });
  },
```

In the XML file I have a weekly hour schema and I would like to insert into the calendar the schema repeated each week.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the fullcalendar do not support "repeated" events.

You will have to create the "repetition" yourself by looking at the start and end arguments and create as many duplicates of your repeating event that are needed within the time interval.

If you have a daily repetion of an event at 10:00-11:00 and have a week view from monday to sunday you will have to generate 7 events with different date to visualize the repetition.

The duplication is done in your event generating code, your xml should not need to be fixed. Just use the xml tags/attributes data to create the correct duplicates.